# excel vba calculate code doesn't calculate some of the formulas in merged cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I calculate the formulas in different sheets using:

```
Sub Calculate_Formulas_otherSheets()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If Sheet.Name Like "*" & strSearch & "_A" Then
         Sheets(Sheet.Name).Calculate
    End If
Next
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If Sheet.Name Like "*" & strSearch & "_B" Then
         Sheets(Sheet.Name).Calculate
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

in these sheets, three of the formulas are in merged cells.

formula 1 in **AY3**

```
=RIGHT(CELL("filename");LEN(CELL("filename"))-FIND("]";CELL("filename")))
```

formula 2 in **AZ3**

```
=IFERROR(RIGHT(LEFT($AY3;FIND("_";$AY3)-4);2);"")
```

formula 3 in **BA3**

```
=IFERROR(RIGHT(LEFT($AY3;FIND("_";$AY3)-3);1);"")
```

everything works perfect if i calculate them manually. But when I do it via the above code, they don't get calculated; other formulas in the sheets do get calculated except these three.

What is going wrong?

By the way, the automatic calculation is off.

***UPDATE***
actually it gets updated in a wrong way: the filename formula gets the sheet name of the sheet in which this vba code is saved as a macro button. How to fix it?

Comment: What if you [specify the used range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834658.aspx) in the `calculate`? Does it work then?

Comment: Provide the second argument to the `CELL` function, otherwise [*the information specified in the `info_type` argument is returned for the last cell that was changed*](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-b98b713d-d3de-4148-829f-80c886af6410?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Comment: @GSerg: Thanks! Yes the reference in cell function was missing! It is OK now.

Comment: @GSerg: put your explanation as the answer to this question and i will accept it for future community use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [documented](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-b98b713d-d3de-4148-829f-80c886af6410?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), the second parameter of the `CELL` function, `reference`, controls the cell you want information about, and:

> If omitted, the information ... is returned for the last cell that was changed.

You are omitting the second parameter, and apparently the last cell that changed happens to be inside a wrong workbook.

Provide a correct cell in the second parameter.